# Ayuda para tratar de usar el componente smart-table de ngx admin sin documentación

Tags: angular, crud, ngx-admin

Necesito usar este componente de Akveo (https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin) pero no encuentro documentación para ello. Todo lo que tengo es un JSON de configuración dentro de la clase SmartTableClientComponent y no sé como utilizarlo.

Precisamente quiero hacer un CRUD usando esto, pero soy un novato buscando alguna guía. Mi idea es que quizás necesito hacer funciones para cada una de estas configuraciones y luego interactuar con mi API (Que ya la tengo) dentro de ellas, pero cómo?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerDataSource } from 'ng2-smart-table';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-smart-table-client',
  templateUrl: './smart-table-client.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./smart-table-client.component.scss'],
})
export class SmartTableClientComponent {

  settings = {
    add: {
      addButtonContent: '<i class="nb-plus"></i>',
      createButtonContent: '<i class="nb-checkmark"></i>',
      cancelButtonContent: '<i class="nb-close"></i>',
    },
    edit: {
      editButtonContent: '<i class="nb-edit"></i>',
      saveButtonContent: '<i class="nb-checkmark"></i>',
      cancelButtonContent: '<i class="nb-close"></i>',
    },
    delete: {
      deleteButtonContent: '<i class="nb-trash"></i>',
      confirmDelete: true,
    },
    columns: {
      clientId: {
        title: 'Client',
        type: 'string',
      },
      name: {
        title: 'Name',
        type: 'string',
      },
      cellphone: {
        title: 'Cellphone',
        type: 'string',
      },
      email: {
        title: 'Email',
        type: 'string',
      },
    },
  };

  source: ServerDataSource;

  constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    this.source = new ServerDataSource(http, { endPoint:'http://localhost:4200/api/client' })
  }

  onDeleteConfirm(event): void {
    if (window.confirm('Remove client?')) {
      event.confirm.resolve();
    } else {
      event.confirm.reject();
    }
  }
}
```

Gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido estas en SO en español, por favor traduce la pregunta al idioma oficial. Adicionalmente te invito a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Perdón, no me había dado cuenta. Ya lo corregí